# Setting text to children nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating some elements (the onclick text will change), and when an element is hovered I would like the onclick text to be displayed so I tried something like this:
*Please note that this is an example, there will be more code in the "aFunction" and it will return a value, so the function is necessary in this example.*

```js
function aFunction(a) {
 return `it works! ${a}`;
}

$('.hastooltip').children("div").on('mouseover', function() {
    console.log(aFunction($(this).attr("onclick"))); // it gets the text successfully
    $(this).children("span").text(aFunction($(this).attr("onclick"))); // but doesn't set it
});
```

```css
.hastooltip{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hastooltip:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
  color: black;
}


.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
  background: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<span class="hastooltip">
  <div id="first-div" onclick="alert('a')">foo</div>
  <span class="tooltip">1</span>
</span>
<span class="hastooltip">
  <div id="second-div" onclick="alert('b')">bar</div>
  <span class="tooltip">2</span>
</span>
<span class="hastooltip">
  <div id="third-div" onclick="alert('c')">baz</div>
  <span class="tooltip">3</span>
</span>
```

However, the text in the hover boxes are not being replaced when the element is hovered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @zer00ne The "tooltip" span text is not being replaced when I hover over the element

Comment: What should replace the tooltips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work because `<span>` is `siblings()` not `children`, try this:

```js
function aFunction(a) {
 return `it works! ${a}`;
}

$('.hastooltip').children("div").on('mouseover', function() {
    console.log(aFunction($(this).attr("onclick"))); // it gets the text successfully
    $(this).siblings("span").text(aFunction($(this).attr("onclick"))); // but doesn't set it
});
```

```css
.hastooltip{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hastooltip:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
  color: black;
}


.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
  background: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<span class="hastooltip">
  <div id="first-div" onclick="alert('a')">foo</div>
  <span class="tooltip">1</span>
</span>
<span class="hastooltip">
  <div id="second-div" onclick="alert('b')">bar</div>
  <span class="tooltip">2</span>
</span>
<span class="hastooltip">
  <div id="third-div" onclick="alert('c')">baz</div>
  <span class="tooltip">3</span>
</span>
```

Comment: You can also use `.next('.tooltip')`

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the `<div>` next to the `<span>` you want to select so `.children()` can'T find it. Use `.siblings()` instead

```js
function aFunction(a) {
  return `it works! ${a}`;
}

$('.hastooltip').children("div").on('mouseover', function() {
  var text = aFunction($(this).attr("onclick"))
  console.log(text); // it gets the text successfully
  $(this).siblings(".tooltip").text(text); // but doesn't set it
});
```

```css
.hastooltip {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hastooltip:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
  color: black;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
  background: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<span class="hastooltip">
  <div id="first-div" onclick="alert('a')">foo</div>
  <span class="tooltip">1</span>
</span>
<span class="hastooltip">
  <div id="second-div" onclick="alert('b')">bar</div>
  <span class="tooltip">2</span>
</span>
<span class="hastooltip">
  <div id="third-div" onclick="alert('c')">baz</div>
  <span class="tooltip">3</span>
</span>
```